# Where can I find the xcode template for opencv on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, templates, opencv

I want to use opencv frequently for iPhone development, so if there is existing xcode template , that will save me a lot time. Also for others who have same purpose.

If not, I need to do it myself.

Thanks for let me know if you know.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've found is OpenCV compiled as "private framework". Easy to drop into your xcode projects. http://www.ient.rwth-aachen.de/cms/software/opencv/

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is now available as a framework for iOS. Just drag and drop into your project. It supports video capture too. See the article and get the example project [here](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV  is now available as a cocoa pod
https://github.com/Fl0p/OpenCV-iOS.git